# How to pull only certain csv's and concat the data from s3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with various files. I am only interested in pulling files that begin with the word 'member' and storing each member file in a list to be concated further into a dataframe.

Currently I am pulling data like this:

```
import boto3

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

obj = s3.Object('my-bucket','member')



file_content = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv(file_content)
```

How ever this is only pulling the member file. I have member files that look like this `'member_1229013','member_2321903'` etc.

How can I read in all the 'member' files, save the data in a list so I can concat later. All column names are the same in all csv's

Comment: I normally recommend download objects to local storage (with `download_file()`) and then using the files directly, rather than using `Body` operations.

Comment: `s3.Object(bucket, key)` requires the Key of a single object. It cannot be used to refer to multiple objects.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am very new to lambda, would you mind providing an exmaple with `download_file()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only download/access one object per API call.

I normally recommend downloading the objects to a local directory, and then accessing them as normal local files. Here is an example of how to download an object from Amazon S3:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

See: [`download_file()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)

If you want to read multiple files, you will first need to obtain a listing of the files (eg with [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), and then access each object individually.

One tip for boto3... There are two ways to make calls: via a Resource (eg using `s3.Object()` or `s3.Bucket()`) or via a Client, which passes everything as parameters.

Comment: Could I download the files 'locally' using lambda you think ?

Comment: An AWS Lambda function is provided 500MB of space in the `/tmp` directory. So, you can download files (using the above code) to the Lambda container and process them "locally" (where 'local' means within the Lambda container). Make sure to delete the files before exiting the Lambda function because the container can be reused and you don't want to run out of disk storage space.

Comment: how does one delete files from lambda? When the container shuts down doesnt that wipe everything?

Comment: The container in which an AWS Lambda function runs _might_ be reused for subsequent calls. This reduces the startup time for later invocations. Therefore, the function should delete any files that it creates in `/tmp` before the function exits. For more details, see: [Understanding Container Reuse in AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/)